# Dynamic connection string for entity framework code first approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using entity framework 6.0 with code first approach and Unit of work pattern. I want to dynamically build the connection string and get the data from the database. Database connection works fine if I have the web.config tag for the connection string. But, I do not want to have a web.config tag for the connection string. I saw many questions related to this, but I did not find related to codefirst approach. Please let me know how to achieve this.

```
-------------------- Repository.cs --------------------

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Commons.DTO;

namespace Repository
{
    public class Repository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        internal CommonsDbContext context;
        internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

        public Repository(CommonsDbContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
            this.context = context;
            this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "")
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

            if (filter != null)
                query = query.Where(filter);

            string[] properties = includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (var includeProperty in properties)
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);

            if (orderBy != null)
                return orderBy(query).ToList();
            else
                return query.ToList();
        }

        public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
        {
            return dbSet.Find(id);
        }

        public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
        {
            dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(object id)
        {
            TEntity entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
            Delete(entityToDelete);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
        {
            if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
                dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
            dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
        }

        public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
            context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public virtual bool IsValid(TEntity entityToValid, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter)
        {
            return dbSet.Where(filter).Any();
        }
    }
}

-------------------- UnitOfWork.cs --------------------
using System;
using Commons.DTO;

namespace Repository
{
    public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        protected CommonsDbContext dbContext = null;

        public UnitOfWork()
        {
            dbContext = new CommonsDbContext();
        }

        public UnitOfWork(CommonsDbContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
            this.dbContext = context;
        }

        public virtual void Save()
        {
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        #region IDisposable Members
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                dbContext.Dispose();
                dbContext = null;
            }
        }

        ~UnitOfWork()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
-------------CommonsDbContext.cs
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Commons.DTO
{
    public class CommonsDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public CommonsDbContext() : base("name=DbContext")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<CommonsDbContext>(null);
        }

        public CommonsDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationMapper());
        }
        public DbSet<Application> Applications { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Entity Framework is a Unit of Work and Repository implementer, why would you want to hide EF? It's both pointless and gives you more work. Also, you are not implementing any of the async features of EF, making your application even slower. You also need to show the constructor for the EF context class

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto although you are right. however he asks for something else.

Comment: @Valkyriee " You also need to show the constructor for the EF context class ". Without the constructor, it's not possible to know. The OP is likely using the constructor that uses the web.config

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Indeed. you are right.

Comment: @Valkyriee, Thank you. I have added CommonsDbContext.cs which takes the connection from web.config --- public CommonsDbContext() : base("name=DbContext"). also I will explore on async features and right way to use EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are specifically passing a connection string name which will only be searched on the `web.config` or `app.config`. Change that to a full connection string if you do not want to use the `web.config`:

```
public class CommonsDbContext : DbContext
{
    //Approach 1:
    private const connectionString = "...";

    public CommonsDbContext() : base(connectionString)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<CommonsDbContext>(null);
    }

    //Approach 2:

    public static CommonsDbContext GetContext()
    {
        var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        // add data here

        return new CommonsDbContext(builder.ConnectionString);
    }

    private CommonsDbContext(string connString) : base(connString)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<CommonsDbContext>(null);
    }
}
```

Do notice, however, that's a much better practice to put connection strings on the `web.config` than anywhere else.